# Access the 'Application Data' folder when using Folder Redirection

Tags: vbscript, special-folders

We use Folder Redirection at my work, and I'm trying to simplify a script that runs when users log on to a Terminal Server.

Is there a way, through `SpecialFolders`, to access the `Application Data` folder?

I ask because if we have to move the location of the Folder Redirection (due to storage limitations), I'd rather not have to go through scripts and manually change things.

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

desktop_location = objShell.SpecialFolders.Item("Desktop")
quick_launch_location = "\\videss\TSUsers\" & user_name & "\Application Data\Microsoft  \Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\"
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use the environment variable

```
Set objShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
appDataLocation=objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%")
quick_launch_location = appDataLocation & "\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\"
```